# Is it possible to get feature names from pandas.get_dummies?

Tags: python, pandas, graphviz, sklearn-pandas

I was wondering if it is possible to get the feature names of pandas.get_dummies so I can pass it to export_graphviz. I am using get_dummies to encode my dataset for sklearn DecisionTreeClassifier. When I export the tree, I would like to have the output of the nodes easier to read.

Thank you in advance!

Edit:

Here is an example of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
#Concatenate the sets
concated = pd.concat([train_file, test_file])

#Get the encoded set
concated_encoded = pd.get_dummies(concated, columns=cols_to_retain)
#Separate the sets
train = concated_encoded[concated_encoded["Train"] == 1]
test = concated_encoded[concated_encoded["Train"] == 0]
train = train.drop(["Train"], axis=1)
test = test.drop(["Train"], axis=1)

X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(train, train_outcome, test_size=0.15)

clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy')
clf = clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred_val = clf.predict(X_val)

import StringIO
import pydot
dot_data = StringIO.StringIO()
```

I want to be able to label the features using the feature_names parameter

```
export_graphviz(clf, out_file=dot_data, feature_names=()) 
graph = pydot.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue()) 
graph.write_png('tree.png')
```

Comment: Maybe you could try to re-phrase this one, possibly also give an example, it would greatly help in understanding what you are asking exactly. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Thanos I added my example of what I am trying to do. I want feature names to appear in my tree that gets exported.

Answer (score 2):

`pd.get_dummies` actually returns a DataFrame (or sparseDataFrame). For a DataFrame `df` you may access the column (or feature) names as you would every DataFrame by requesting the columns attribute of the DataFrame object using, `df.columns` as in the following sample:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'a'], 'B': ['b', 'a', 'c'],
                'C': [1, 2, 3]})  #creates sample dataframe

>>> df_dummified = pd.get_dummies(df)  #returns new coded dataframe

>>> columns = df_dummified.columns  #returns index object holding new column names

>>> columns.tolist()  #converts the index object to a list

['C', 'A_a', 'A_b', 'B_a', 'B_b', 'B_c']
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use [pd.get_dummies](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) the new columns receive names corresponding to the values of that features in the dataframe. In the following example from the docs you can see how the dummy columns receive the name `<prefix>_<value>`:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'a'], 'B': ['b', 'a', 'c'],
                    'C': [1, 2, 3]})
>>> pd.get_dummies(df, prefix=['col1', 'col2'])
   C  col1_a  col1_b  col2_a  col2_b  col2_c
0  1       1       0       0       1       0
1  2       0       1       1       0       0
2  3       1       0       0       0       1
```

Therefore you likely just need to use:

```
feature_names = list(train.columns)
export_graphviz(clf, out_file=dot_data, feature_names=feature_names)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another idea making use of the `prefix` parameter of `get_dummies()`. Below a single string is used to prefix all feature names created. You can work out a more complex scheme as `prefix` can also take a dict or list.

```py
visa_data_copy = pd.get_dummies(visa_data_copy, columns=categorical_cols, prefix='UID_001')

added_dummy_cols = [item for item in list(visa_data_copy.columns.values) if item.startswith('UID_001')]
```

So `added_dummy_cols` will end up being a list of the column names that `get_dummies()` added for you and you can use it later however you need.