# Retrieve column names created by pandas get_dummies

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a good way to get the column names created when you run `get_dummies` on a dataframe. For example,

```
import pandas as pd

# set up a dataframe with one numeric and two categocial columns
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "numeric_1": [1, 2, 3, 4],
    "cat_1": ['high', 'low', 'high', 'low'],
    "cat_2": ['blue', 'blue', 'green', 'green']
})

# identify the categorical columns
categorical_colnames = ['cat_1', 'cat_2']

# get dummies
df = pd.get_dummies(df, categorical_colnames)
```

For this dataframe, I'd want to see:

> ['cat_1_high', 'cat_1_low', 'cat_2_blue', 'cat_2_green']

The code I use to do this is clunky, and I'm wondering if there is anything better. I searched the docs and it doesn't seem like there is an option to return this when you run `pd.get_dummies`. Here is the code I use:

```
nominal_prefixes = [s + "_" for s in categorical_colnames]
nominal_colnames = []
for x in nominal_prefixes:
    cols_x = [col for col in df if col.startswith(x)]
    nominal_colnames.append(cols_x)

nominal_colnames = [item for sublist in nominal_colnames for item in sublist]
```

With `nominal_colnames`, I create the list that I want, but this is clunky and I was hoping for something better.  I have to do this pretty often in my code and I assume other pandas users do too. I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37077254/is-it-possible-to-get-feature-names-from-pandas-get-dummies) is similar, but it does not address my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just filter by column prefix:

```
nominal_colnames = df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('cat_')].values
```

If you need exact prefixes pass a tuple of column names:

```
nominal_colnames = (df.columns[df.columns.str
                    .startswith(tuple(categorical_colnames))].values)
```

---

```
['cat_1_high' 'cat_1_low' 'cat_2_blue' 'cat_2_green']
```

Comment: This works, and it's less clunky, but `df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith(tuple(categorical_colnames))].values`. I would think that pandas would have an intuitive solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) and a regex:

```
import re

pattern = f"^({'|'.join(map(re.escape, categorical_colnames))})"
# ^(cat_1|cat_2)

out = df.filter(regex=pattern)
```

*NB. if you have no special characters `pattern = f"^({'|'.join(categorical_colnames)})"` is sufficient.*

Output:

```
   cat_1_high  cat_1_low  cat_2_blue  cat_2_green
0        True      False        True        False
1       False       True        True        False
2        True      False       False         True
3       False       True       False         True
```

If you just need the column names:

```
import re

pat = re.compile(f"^({'|'.join(map(re.escape, categorical_colnames))})")

cols = list(filter(pat.match, df.columns))
```

Output: `['cat_1_high', 'cat_1_low', 'cat_2_blue', 'cat_2_green']`

Comment: We'd then also need to add `out.columns.tolist()`, which works, but it creates another dataframe first.

Comment: @mikey I thought you wanted to slice the DataFrame, see update if you just need the column names ;)

Answer (score 0):

In this particular example, all the dummy-coded columns in the result will have `dtype('bool')`, while `numeric_1` will be kept unaltered with `dtype('int64')`.

That being the case, you can also use [`df.select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) to filter on the columns that you want, adding [`df.columns`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.columns.html) to get the column labels:

```
df.select_dtypes('bool')

   cat_1_high  cat_1_low  cat_2_blue  cat_2_green
0        True      False        True        False
1       False       True        True        False
2        True      False       False         True
3       False       True       False         True

df.select_dtypes('bool').columns
Index(['cat_1_high', 'cat_1_low', 'cat_2_blue', 'cat_2_green'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: This would only work if I didn't have other boolean columns though

Comment: Evidently, which is why I added "In this particular example". *Assuming* you don't have other columns with `dtype('bool')`, this would work. But the other solutions offered assume something as well, namely that none of your other columns start with, e.g., `"cat_2..."` . In such a case, they would also be selected :). More in general, the issue could be avoided if you either store `df.columns` in a variable before overwriting `df`, or if you create a new df. I.e., in that case you could do: `list(df2.columns.difference(df.columns))` (though even that solution could have "edge cases"!).